# How to check database has not been unmounted/ marked for overwrite

Tags: exchange

When restoring  Exchange with  use of  VSS API try to catch errors in 
cases: 
1) when  restoring database has not been unmounted 
  Exchange  2010 generate error  on PreRestore call and write error to 
Windows Application log -all ok , 
but for Exchange2007   PreRestore succeded and write error toWindows 
Application  log only

2)when restored database has been unmounted but has not been  marked 
for overwrite 
Exchange 2007/2010 generate error to Windows Application  log but 
PreRestore call succeded 
How can I  know from application (via VSS API -   not from Windows 
Application log) that error has happend (database has not been 
unmounted  and has not been marked for overwrite. ) 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try calling GetWriterStatus on the Writer that you are using. This might flag an Retryable error.